# How can I implement MVVM pattern with riverpod annotation in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, riverpod-generator, riverpod-annotation

I am trying to make MVVM architecture with riverpod annotation. And Here are some example code snippets.

```
import ...

part 'invite_customer_usecase.g.dart';

@riverpod
class InviteCustomerUseCase extends _$InviteCustomerUseCase {
  final ShopRepository _shopRepository;
  final UntactRepository _untactRepository;
  final ManagerRepository _managerRepository;
  final UserRepository _userRepository;

  InviteCustomerUseCase(
      {required ShopRepository shopRepository,
      required UntactRepository untactRepository,
      required ManagerRepository managerRepository,
      required UserRepository userRepository})
      : _shopRepository = shopRepository,
        _untactRepository = untactRepository,
        _managerRepository = managerRepository,
        _userRepository = userRepository;

  @override
  InviteCustomerUseCase build() {
    return InviteCustomerUseCase(
        shopRepository: _shopRepository,
        untactRepository: _untactRepository,
        managerRepository: _managerRepository,
        userRepository: _userRepository);
  }
}
```

```
import ...

part 'lobby_viewmodel.g.dart';

@riverpod
class LobbyViewModel extends _$LobbyViewModel {
  final UntactRepository _untactRepository;
  final ShopRepository _shopRepository;
  final ManagerRepository _managerRepository;
  final InviteCustomerUseCase _inviteCustomerUseCase;

  LobbyViewModel(
      {required UntactRepository untactRepository,
      required ShopRepository shopRepository,
      required ManagerRepository managerRepository,
      required InviteCustomerUseCase inviteCustomerUseCase}) :
        _untactRepository = untactRepository,
        _shopRepository = shopRepository,
        _managerRepository = managerRepository,
        _inviteCustomerUseCase = inviteCustomerUseCase;

  @override
  LobbyViewModel build() {
    return LobbyViewModel(
        untactRepository: _untactRepository,
        shopRepository: _shopRepository,
        managerRepository: _managerRepository,
        inviteCustomerUseCase: _inviteCustomerUseCase);
  }
}
```

And

````
part 'local_storage_provider.g.dart';

@riverpod
FlutterSecureStorage secureStorage(SecureStorageRef ref) => const FlutterSecureStorage();

@riverpod
ManagerLocalStorage managerLocalStorage(ManagerLocalStorageRef ref) => ManagerLocalStorageImpl(storage: ref.watch(secureStorageProvider));```
````

```
part 'repository_provider.g.dart';

@riverpod
ShopRepository shopRepository(ShopRepositoryRef ref) => ShopRepositoryImpl(dio: authDio(), managerLocalStorage: ref.watch(managerLocalStorageProvider));

@riverpod
UntactRepository untactRepository(UntactRepositoryRef ref) => UntactRepositoryImpl(authDio: authDio());

@riverpod
ManagerRepository managerRepository(ManagerRepositoryRef ref) => ManagerRepositoryImpl(localStorage: ref.watch(managerLocalStorageProvider), dataSource: ref.watch(managerDataSourceProvider));

@riverpod
UserRepository userRepository(UserRepositoryRef ref) => UserRepositoryImpl(dataSource: ref.watch(userDataSourceProvider));
```

At the moment I defined providers like this. But I read and watched videos and it seems like I don't need to define like this. But just @riverpod annotation on the top of class keyword seems like it does the same thing.

My problem is

```
  @override
  InviteCustomerUseCase build() {
    return InviteCustomerUseCase(
        shopRepository: _shopRepository,
        untactRepository: _untactRepository,
        managerRepository: _managerRepository,
        userRepository: _userRepository);
  }
```

This part. I think it is a problem?

Some people wrote like this

```
class LobbyViewModel extends _$LobbyViewModel {
  final UntactRepository _untactRepository = ref.watch(untactRepositoryProvider);
  final ShopRepository _shopRepository = ref.watch(shopRepositoryProvider);
  final ManagerRepository _managerRepository = ref.watch(managerRepositoryProvider);
  final InviteCustomerUseCase _inviteCustomerUseCase = ref.watch(inviteCustomerProvider);

  // No constructor
}
```

And I think this is a problem because I can't inject when I test. And also, when people use this class other team member won't know if it needs those repositories or usecases.

So, I am trying to use constructor.

They can be singletons. Only ViewModel can be shared in different pages(or screens). which means, sometimes, it needs to be `invalidate/refresh` or `keepAlive` when you use pop or push in router.

And of course, generally, way. I'd like to use `ref.watch()`, `ref.read`, ... in Widgets. I am using HookConsumerWidget (from flutter_hooks package.)

So, How can I improve my code?

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that the `build` method in your classes should return some state of your class. Recall that you have it returning an instance of the class. Take a look at this example - [(Async)NotifierProvider](https://docs-v2.riverpod.dev/docs/providers/notifier_provider).

Then, in the `build` method of your classes, you can safely watch (use `ref.watch` and `ref.listen`) to your `shopRepository`, `UntactRepository` and others and quietly get their instances.

In short, try doing something like this:

```
import ...

part 'lobby_viewmodel.g.dart';

@riverpod
class LobbyViewModel extends _$LobbyViewModel {
  late final UntactRepository _untactRepository;
  late final ShopRepository _shopRepository;
  late final ManagerRepository _managerRepository;
  late final InviteCustomerUseCase _inviteCustomerUseCase;

  // your state can also be of type void
  @override
  MyStateLobby build() {
    _untactRepository = ref.watch(untactRepositoryProvider);
    _untactRepository = ref.watch(shopRepositoryProvider);
    _untactRepository = ref.watch(managerRepositoryProvider);
    _inviteCustomerUseCase = ref.watch(inviteCustomerUseCaseProvider);

    // Get data from these repositories to change your state

    return MyStateLobby(...);
  }
}
```

Useful links:

- [How to Auto-Generate your Providers with Flutter Riverpod Generator](https://codewithandrea.com/articles/flutter-riverpod-generator/)
- [Flutter App Architecture with Riverpod: An Introduction](https://codewithandrea.com/articles/flutter-app-architecture-riverpod-introduction/)

Comment: I don't get what `state` mean. What will be the state and What does it build? I thought it will build the class. Can it be empty? And so, how can I use the ViewModel in the widgets? And I found @Riverpod and @riverpod. I've heard @Riverpod is used for classes. Is there any differences?

Comment: Your state can be `void` and then this class will be what you expect it to be. Familiarize yourself with the links I've secured. As for the annotation, they are two exactly the same annotation, except that `@Riverpod()` may have additional parameters inside.

Comment: Thank you. But I got initialization error. It doesn't call the build. I might misuse it. because I defined other provider and used it. I think I need to use `lobbyViewModelProvider` which is generated from this class. But ref.watch(lobbyViewModelProvider) says that `This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.`. I guess that's because the build() returns nothing. Can I return LobbyViewModel this(the class itself)?

Comment: Yeah, just use `ref.watch(lobbyViewModelProvider.notifier)`